# SSL Configuration for Http Client

Tags: java, spring-boot, httpclient, spring-resttemplate

this question might sound I bit dummy but I have researched many questions/answers here and can't find the answer for my case.

Currently I am using [RestTemplate library](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html) to make HTTP requests for my java library that I am currently working on. In order to have successful HTTP call to HTTPS URLs i needed to add a SSL configuration for my HTTP client. Something like this:

```
   clientBuilder
                .disableCookieManagement()
                .setDefaultRequestConfig(requestConfig)
                .setSSLSocketFactory(new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(SSLContexts.custom()
                        .loadTrustMaterial(null, new TrustSelfSignedStrategy())
                        .build()));
```

So this library is supposed to be shipped to the user as a jar executable application and I know that using self-signed SSL certificates is not a good idea for general usage since there might have web servers that do not acknowledge it. I read that If I get a signed SSL certificate then I should save the proper keys on Keystore and also use Trustore to acknowledge the server's certificate. I do not think I can just pass Keystore and Trustore to the client who executes my java library, so my question here is, does Java has a built-in SSL certificate, so I could somehow just do some configuration on HTTP client and the built-in certificates would be used. As far as I know, node.js offers something like that.

Could anyone just give me a explanation of how this works for java spring-boot?

Answer (score 0):

There are two separate certificate verifications that could be happening. To connect to a server using https, you need to receive the server's certificate and validate it using a truststore.

In addition, it is possible for you to have a client certificate, and to pass that to the server so it can authenticate your client. Unless you have been told you need to do that, you don't. Unless the server has been specifically configured to do it, it isn't possible. If it is what you need to do, you need to obtain a client certificate, install it into a keystore and use that keystore in your client.

So for normal https, you do not need a keystore.

Whether you need "TrustSelfSignedStrategy" depends on the server.

If the server has a valid signed SSL certificate, you do not need to do anything special, RestTemplate will just work.

If the server has a self-signed certificate, you need to either configure the client to accept any self-signed certificate, or load the server's certificate into a truststore so the client knows to accept that specific certificate.